# MPAndoirdChart Piechart text overlapping

Tags: android, charts, pie-chart, label, mpandroidchart

In piechart with 3 values, when one value is big and 2 others much smaller, their lables overlap each other. Which solution can be for that problem? [image]?

Answer (score 0):

There is really not much you can do if you have that **big differences between the values** of the chart slices (500.000 vs 37.000 vs. 3.000) as far as I can see. It's clear that in that case some slices will be much bigger than others.

What you could do is stop displaying values in the barchart in general.
Instead, maybe display letters or something.